# Azure maps - point vs feature vs shape

Tags: azure-maps

I am new to Azure maps and reading through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-pin).

This blurb describes Points, Features and Shapes.

[image]

But it doesn't really help me understand why I would use one over the other.  Can someone help me understand the differences and/or point me to some articles that shed light on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please give [this](https://macwright.org/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html) article a try and see if it's helpful. It describes what different geometries are available in the GeoJSON standard and what's point vs shape vs feature.

Comment: In summary format: Points, LineString, Polygon,  MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon are Geometries. Geometries define that shape that is rendered on the map. A feature consists of a geometry and additional custom properties (i.e. name). A feature collection is basically an array of features. GeoJSON objects have no functionality on their own, they are just JSON. Updating one of these requires manually removing/updating data on the map. The Shape class allows you to wrap these with a class that makes updating the map easy.

Answer (score 3):

AzureMaps, like many other map libraries, uses the [GeoJSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) format to encode geographic data structures.

This format includes Geometry, Feature and FeatureCollection objects.

**Geometry:**

GeoJSON supports different geometry types:

- [Point](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.2)
- [MultiPoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.3)
- [LineString](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.4)
- [MultiLineString](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.5)
- [Polygon](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6)
- [MultiPolygon](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.7)
- [GeometryCollection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.8)

These geometry types, except for the GeometryCollection, are represented in a Geometry object with the following properties:

- `type` A GeoJSON type descriptor
- `coordinates` A collection of coordinates

Example. Point Geometry object:

```
{
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [0, 0]
}
```

The GeometryCollection is also a Geometry object, but with the following properties:

- `type` A GeoJSON type descriptor with value "GeometryCollection"
- `geometries` A collection of Geometry objects

Example: GeometryCollection Geometry object

```
{
  "type": "GeometryCollection",
  "geometries": [
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [0, 0]
   },
   // N number of Geometry objects
  ]
}
```

**Feature:**

Geometry objects with additional properties are called Feature objects:

- `type` A GeoJSON type descriptor with value "Feature"
- `geometry` The Geometry object
- `properties` N number of additional properties

Example. Point feature object

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [0, 0]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Null Island"
    // N number of additional properties
  }
}
```

**Feature collection:**

Sets of features are contained by FeatureCollection objects:

- `type` A GeoJSON type descriptor with value "FeatureCollection"
- `features` A collection of Feature objects

Example. Feature collection with a Point Feature object

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Null Island"
        // N number of additional properties
      }
    }
    // N number of Feature objects
  ]
}
```

---

**Shape:**

Since GeoJSON objects are only geographic data structures and have no functionality on their own, Azure Maps provides the [Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.shape?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest) helper class to make it easy to update and maintain them.

The Shape class wraps a [Geometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.data.geometry?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest&viewFallbackFrom=azure-iot-typescript-latest) or a [Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.data.feature?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest&viewFallbackFrom=azure-iot-typescript-latest).

- Geometry: Base class that constructs a GeoJSON Geometry object.
- Feature: Class that constructs a GeoJSON Feature object.

Examples.

Creating a Shape by passing in a Geometry and an object containing properties.

```
var shape1 = new atlas.Shape(
  new atlas.data.Point([0, 0], {
    myProperty: 1,
    // N number of additional properties
  })
)
```

Creating a Shape using a Feature.

```
var shape2 = new atlas.Shape(
  new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([0, 0]), {
    myProperty: 1,
    // N number of additional properties
  })
)
```